# Symbol not found on netbeans visual database explorer module

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to make the Visual Database Explorer at Apache Netbeans 15 from this tutorial:

https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorials/nbm-visual_library2.html

Unfortunately on the first class I get this error:

"cannot find symbol
symbol:   class HelpCtx
location: package org.openide.util"

Its seems the import of "org.openide.util.HelpCtx;" must be obsolete by the time tutorial written.

The class that this error appears is:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.ConnectionManager;
import org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseConnection;
import org.netbeans.modules.db.explorer.action.BaseAction;
import org.openide.nodes.Node;
import org.openide.util.HelpCtx;

public final class ShowDatabaseStructureAction extends BaseAction {

    @Override
    protected void performAction(Node[] nodes) {

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean enable(Node[] activatedNodes) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Show Database Structure";
    }

    @Override
    public HelpCtx getHelpCtx() {
        return HelpCtx.DEFAULT_HELP;
    }

}
```

Does anyone who have completed this tutorial can help? or is there a newer version for this tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the tutorial (Setting Up the Module, point 5), you need to add some dependencies.

In your case you need to add a dependency on the "Utilities API" module.

Edit your module `Properties`, then select `Libraries`, `Module Dependencies` tab, then click and `Add dependency...`

Another way, more convenient, is to just click on the hint (light bulb) where the symbol is undefined (see image example below).

[image]